# I am trying to access the test points executed in my ADO via REST API in my power Bi report but it throws me an error

Tags: azure-devops, powerbi-desktop, azure-devops-rest-api, test-plan

ERROR -

Microsoft Internet Explorer's Enhanced Security Configuration is currently enabled on your environment. This enhanced level of security prevents our web integration experiences from displaying or performing correctly. To continue with your operation please disable this configuration or contact your administrator.

We have tried everything else and this is our last option to access test point execution results in my AZURE DevOps.

I couldn't find this settings anywhere so I could disable it. I also tried to run the API query in my power bi desktop on a server to see if it works but the same error appeared again but if I try any other demo rest api query from internet, it works and displays the data.

How do I get my data in power BI using Rest API ?
Please help.